# Batch rename files and organize them Bat Script

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, file-rename

Friends, I need to rename pdf files to a certain standard. For that I made the following script:

```
c:

cd \importation

if not exist %1 goto end
md %~n1 
move %1 %~n1\P%~n1_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf 

if not exist %2 goto end
md %~n2 
move %2 %~n2\P%~n2_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf 

if not exist %3 goto end
md %~n3
move %3 %~n3\P%~n3_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf 

if not exist %4 goto end
md %~n4 
move %4 %~n4\P%~n4_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf 

if not exist %5 goto end
md %~n5 
move %5 %~n5\P%~n5_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf 

if not exist %6 goto end
md %~n6 
move %6 %~n6\P%~n6_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf

if not exist %7 goto end
md %~n7 
move %7 %~n7\P%~n7_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf

if not exist %8 goto end
md %~n8
move %8 %~n8\P%~n8_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf

if not exist %9 goto end
md %~n9 
move %9 %~n9\P%~n9_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf



:end
```

It turns out that the script only modifies up to 9 files at a time. Does anyone know how I can make this change to all files in the folder? Sometimes there are 100,200 or even more pdfs

Comment: Can you describe what the current script does? I suspect it'll be trivial to do in a single line in PowerShell, but my batch script variable substitution knowledge is lacking :)

Comment: I drag the files into the .bat and the script creates a folder with the file name (for each pdf). The PDF is moved to its folder and renamed with the following pattern:

P[file name]_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf

@MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: Maybe just a one line batch file will do: ```@If Not "%~1" == "" For %%G In (%*) Do @MD "%%~dpG%%~nG" 2>NUL && Move /Y "%%~G" "%%~dpG%%~nG\P%%~nG_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume%%~xG"```.

Comment: So if `%1` is `abc.pdf`, then `%~n1` = `abc`?

Comment: Please note my offered solution above will only work if the length of all of the characters in all of their absolute paths do not exceed command line length limits. As you clearly wish to drag and drop, from Windows Explorer, more than nine files, please be aware that the depth of the file tree, and length of their filenames could seriously affect your decision to choose that methodology.

Comment: It worked very well my friend, it worked perfectly. Thanks @Compo

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yes

Comment: @Compo é possivel o .bat verificar se os arquivos tem pontos ou traços e removelos antes de executar uma operação? Estava procurando por REGEX em .bat mas meu conhecimento é limitado nesta linguagem.

Comment: @Passos, yes it is possible to verify that the files have dots or dashes and remove them before performing the operation. It simply requires an additional step, i.e save the output `%%~nG` to a variable, then perform variable expansion and substitution on it replacing each of those characters with nothing. The additional step would require enabling delayed expansion and would be better as multiple lines instead of just one. However, technically, that is another question, and as you've seemingly already accepted a [[tag:PowerShell]] answer, there's not much point in me submitting the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Get-ChildItem` to discover the files, then inspect their `BaseName` property to get the file name without the extension:

```
$rootFolder = 'C:\importation'

Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -File -Filter *.pdf |ForEach-Object {
  # create new folder
  $newFolder = mkdir -Path $rootFolder -Name $_.BaseName
  # construct target path
  $targetPath = Join-Path $newFolder.FullName "P$($_.BaseName)_V1_A0V0_T07-54-369-664_S00001_Volume.pdf"
  # move file
  $_ |Move-Item -Destination $targetPath
}
```

Comment: Very good, thank you for the availability, it also worked  @MathiasR.Jessen

Comment: @Passos, typically when an answer worked and solved your problem, we select the answer as correct by selecting the grey tick mark on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
# Define variables
$Folder = "C:\myfolder"
$OldFileName = "OldFileName1.pdf"
$NewFileName = "NewFileName1.pdf"

# Get all files in the folder non-recursively
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder

# For each file
foreach ($File in $Files){

    # If file matches the OldFileName
    If ($File.Name -eq $OldFileName){

        # Rename the file to the new name
        Rename-Item -Path $File.FullName -NewName $NewFileName

    }

}
```

Comment: what about the  md and move in the provided code sample of the question? ;-)

Comment: I believe 'move' is the way to rename an item in batch

Comment: The OP was draggging and dropping the files onto the script, so to properly answer the question your script should be processing the input, not creating variables to be modified prior to running the script directly.